# Error en instancia en AWS Educate

Tags: wordpress, aws

me pregunto cual podria ser el origen o la causa, de este error que me arroja en la plataforma de AWS Educate, cuando quiero crear una instancia de wordpress?
[image: <code>introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí</code>]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando tienes una cuenta de AWS Educate, esta tiene restricciones en los diferentes instancias de la consola, es decir para activar WordPress si necesitas pagar el uso de este instancia.

Comment: Ahunque diga free la instancia?

Comment: Si, las instancias gratuitas cuentan con muchas limitaciones, solo puedes realzar cosas muy básicas.